# django-crm install

Tags: django, crm, pip

I am trying to install django-crm. I am using pip to install it:

```
pip install django-crm
```

I am getting:

```
Downloading/unpacking django-crm
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirements django-crm
No distributions at all found for django-crm
Storing complete log in C:\users\User\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

Edit:

The log file includes the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 06/27/12 00:33:50
Downloading/unpacking django-crm
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/django_crm
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/django_crm: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/django_crm when looking for download links for django-crm
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for django-crm:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/django_crm/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/django_crm/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/django_crm/: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/django_crm/ when looking for download links for django-crm
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-crm
No distributions at all found for django-crm
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 954, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 152, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for django-crm
```

Can anyone help me out? How do I install django-crm? Is there anywhere I can see a demo of it instead of installing it myself?

Thanks!!

Comment: It is saying that such a archive does not exist. What is the output of the command:
pip search django-crm?
Also, show us the log file.

Comment: OK, I found it:svn checkout http://django-crm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ django-crm-read-only

Comment: @matcheek I added the log file to the question

Comment: @matcheek I see what you found, but how do I install it?

Comment: See sample project for details

Comment: thanks, but I do not see how to download it. Do I have to go page by page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no PyPI entry for Django CRM, give pip the location where it could find the package:

```
$ pip install svn+http://django-crm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/#egg=django-crm
```

It works for me.

Comment: @Meir, you need `svn` installed in your computer to use the command above. If you are using linux, try `sudo apt-get install svn`, for Mac OS X, try `brew install svn`.

Answer (score 1):

try all new django crm in github

https://github.com/MicroPyramid/Django-CRM

Comment: Is this using mysql as backend?